# Conditional text field with radio button in joomla registration module (joomla 3.3.3)

Tags: php, xml, joomla, radio-button

I just managed to add a custom field in registration form thanks to an answer here:
[Adding custom field in default joomla 3.1.1 registration form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336842/adding-custom-field-in-default-joomla-3-1-1-registration-form) and I'm able to add user information after adding the correct field in the mysql talble.

But now I would like to do more: i've a radio field type, and I would like that if user checks the right option a text field appears, or either, if the not correct one is chosen, the textbox disappear. Becouse I already have the radio and text fields.

Like: U drink beer?

yes--> if checked shows a textbox like: "Say us wich one you prefer!"

no --> No textbox appears.

Now I've the radio field and the text field, but the text field have to appear only with the "yes" option.

Joomla has been installed 1 hour ago, i added only language plugin. Nothing else has been done.

Thanks, and really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support request using some third party software (here: Joomla) with some other third party extensions. It's not a concrete programming question of the person writing code him- or herself.

Comment: If you do not fully understand the answer given in a previous question, please leave a comment [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336842/adding-custom-field-in-default-joomla-3-1-1-registration-form).

Comment: @hakre, I understood everything of that post, becouse I can do what is explained there. I don't use third party extension, I thought this was a php/xml question, since the programming language is that. Btw, thanks for help ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add, or remove, or show, or hide... html content dynamically You must use Javascript.

Try to learn more about jQuery, this is a pretty easy syntax who give you You possibility to handle you html content.

[link to jQuery javascript framework](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: I will search how to use jquery with joomla, thanks!